# Need ''The diameter of the prime graph of a finite group'' by Lucido

Tags: reference-request

I need a paper by Lucido, I am studying prime graphs to make a presentation in Group theory class, which is [here](http://www.degruyter.com/dg/viewarticle/j$002fjgth.1999.2.issue-2$002fjgth.1999.011$002fjgth.1999.011.xml) on degruyter. Now, my college doesn't have access to degruyter (although is has to many other famous journals), and paper is too costly to buy (42 dollars). Is there a way I can get access to it. 
Can someone here send me (email) this paper if they have access. I really cannot afford 42 dollars being a student.

Comment: You could try asking on [scholar.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/scholar/).